# What is the profit of static method in JDBC?

Tags: java

In JDBC when you need to get a connection, you have to load a class Driver first. You do it via invocation of `Class.forName`.

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

This class method load a class and add it to DriverManager holder:

```
static {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then to get connection you have to invoke a static method `getConnection`.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DbUrl, Username, Password);
```

`getConnection` method creates a connection using separate thread and so on...

My question is why authors of JDK are using a static method: `Class.forName`, `getConnection`. What is the role of "static" approach?

Comment: I think the reason for the `Class.forName` is to verify the class can be found in the classpath - it doesn't load anything. Otherwise your program would fail when you use your specific jdbc connection

Comment: `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` is no longer required

Comment: As for DriverManager.getConnection being static, why not? What would be the benefit of having to create an instance of DriverManager first?

Comment: My question is related to the role of static methods in JDBC in general. Why we need to use them instead of instance methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously you needed to explicitly load the class with `Class.forName()` because the drivers contained initialization code that would be run at class loading time (it's no longer required for new drivers).

`DriverManager` will register available `Drivers`, after which you can use the static `getConnection()` method to open a connection using any of the registered drivers. The driver chosen will depend on the jdbc URL used, and the static factory method will then return a "native" connection object that implements the `Connection` interface.

As you can easily see, there's no advantage to any of those operations being non-static, but after getting a `Connection` you no longer use static methods.

So `Class.forName()` is static for obvious reasons and `DriverManager.getConnection()` is static because it's a factory method for different JDBC driver `Connection` implementations.

Comment: Why we cannot just use an instance method only?

Comment: Almost all method of `DriverManager` are static.

Comment: It's full of factory methods. It's possible to bypass `DriverManager` completely, but it would result in database dependent code and would be a bad idea generally. Multiple instances of `DriverManager` on the other hand would be unnecessary too.

Comment: > it would result in database dependent code

Comment: If I create a Driver via `new` (without a factory method) and invoke a `connect` method manually how it woould result in dependent code? `org.postgresql.Driver`

Comment: You would be using a class from the db-specific driver, instead of using only Java interfaces. In most cases it probably wouldn't make much difference, but with `DriverManager` it's done with respect to encapsulation. Therefore you don't *need* to know what's inside the driver jar, because you'll be using the standardized Java form.